# ionic plugins not found

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm starting with ionic and after testing the plugins I do not work any, I'm following what the official documentation tells me and even download an example to see if it's my problem

https://github.com/anilkumar007/Battery-Status

I download this example and execute ionic

```
ionic serve
```

It runs the browser but with say that it does not work to me I mean that there is no effect where there would have to be for example in the example that I passed I would have to display in the browser the percentage of the battery or in the case of the computer would have to Being 100% also compile it to apk and tested on my mobile but I am not using the following versions.

> ionic -> 2.1.14 cordova -> 6.3.1 nodejs -> 5.5.0

Before I had the version of Cordova 6.4.0 and decide to download version to see if this was the problem but I still have no results, I have already tried almost all this week and I still do not make any plugin

Comment: Ionic plugins will not work with `ionic serve` as it serves to a browser and your browser doesn't have a battery. Try to use `ionic run` instead to run your application in an emulator.

Comment: O, you tried it on a mobile... Maybe try this plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/batteryStatus/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this it to use the livereload functionality. First you have to install the plugins that you need to use, so that they can get compiled in the binary. Then run `ionic run android -l`. Now the app will run on your phone, and will update every time you update the app on your computer.

Livereload is basically just like `ionic serve` except that you will be running on a device/simulator instead of running on your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i will try if it works for me Ionic android -l but I have a question Why does it work with phonegap and not with ionic? With phonegap add the plugin, start the server and try it with the browser and if it works

Comment: As I knowed, some plugin not work with the browser when you user ionic serve, this tutorial may helpful for you : https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/07/monitor-device-battery-status-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: Thanks for the help, really served me and is running on the virtual machine android the only thing to add is that I did not work until I added cordova-android Npm install cordova-android@6.0.0 And now compiles perfect. Is there a difference between using and not using cordova-android?

Comment: When you use ionic serve, it will load your app by browser, others hand ionic run android will launch the Android emulator.